# Queue printing starts newline midway through each iteration

Tags: c, queue, printf

I'm trying to print what's held in a queue, implemented using a linked list. The information is printed, however the format is a little odd. My code compiles without errors or warnings. The numbers are randomly generated and the text is just random letters for right now. I've intentionally left out my main function and header inclusions as these are not the problem. The output is all supposed to be on one line, rather, the terminal displays it as like this:

```
3434: dfdsf 
: sdfdsf
3432: dsfsd 
: fsdf
4564: sdfsd 
: fsdf
7869: sdfsdf 
: sdf
9874: sdfsd
: fsdf
```

Where as I want my result to look like:

```
5432: fdklfn: nfjdsf
```

So somehow, my code is jumping a line at the exact same place each iteration.

Here is my linked list:

```
typedef struct macrotreat{
  int num;
  char name[30];
  char desc[100];
  struct macrotreat *next;
} treat;
```

Here is my function code:

```
void print(treat * front) {

  int i;
  treat *newNode = front;

  for(i = 0; newNode && i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d: %s: %s", newNode->num, newNode->name, newNode->desc);
    newNode = newNode->next;
  }
}
```

What am I missing and how do I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: do the names and descs have newlines in them?

Comment: The best advice here is to start your debugger and single step through the printing code. Check all variables involved.

Comment: No, none of the names or descriptions have newlines, just characters. Which is why it confuses me so much.

Comment: The reality of the observed output disproves your imagination that _none of the names or descriptions have newlines_.